# Dropbox API V2 list_file_members/batch empty results

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm currently trying to work with the Dropbox list_file_members API endpoint, as it appears to me to be the only place to find out who owns a file (
 see follow example result taken from the documentation page )

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "access_type": {
                ".tag": "owner"
            },
            "user": {
                "account_id": "dbid:AAH4f99T0taONIb-OurWxbNQ6ywGRopQngc",
                "same_team": true,
                "team_member_id": "dbmid:abcd1234"
            },
            "permissions": [],
            "is_inherited": false
        }
    ],
    "groups":[...]
    ...
}
```

However, when I call the API on a single file I get the follow

```
{
  "users": [],
  "groups": [
    {
      "access_type": {
        ".tag": "editor"
      },
      "permissions": [],
      "is_inherited": true,
      "group": {
        "group_name": "Everyone at TEAM_NAME_HERE",
        "group_id": "g:GROUP_ID_HERE",
        "member_count": 6,
        "group_management_type": {
          ".tag": "company_managed"
        },
        "group_type": {
          ".tag": "team"
        },
        "is_owner": false,
        "same_team": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "invitees": []
}
```

This result contains no owner information, so I'm assuming this is because everyone has the same access levels ??

The problem worsens when I try to call files in batches using the sharing_list_file_members/batch endpoint, I get the following result

```
[
  {
    "file": "id:THIS_IS_MY_FILE_ID",
    "result": {
      ".tag": "result",
      "members": {
        "users": [],
        "groups": [],
        "invitees": []
      },
      "member_count": 0
    }
  }
]
```

Obviously this is even less helpful, this is the same when I access the API via my own PHP, as well as the API explorer, could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong and why I'm getting no results from users and even groups when done in batches  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [/2/sharing/list_file_members](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_file_members) endpoint is documented as:

> Use to obtain the members who have been invited to a file, both inherited and uninherited members.

The [/2/sharing/list_file_members/batch](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_file_members-batch) endpoint is documented as:

> Get members of multiple files at once. The arguments to this route are more limited, and the limit on query result size per file is more strict. To customize the results more, use the individual file endpoint.
>   Inherited users are not included in the result, and permissions are not returned for this endpoint.

It sounds like the file for your example is in a team folder, and so the group listed for your non-batch example is the team group, i.e., an inherited group. The documentation indicates that this group isn't expected when using the batch endpoint.

Comment: Ah, thank you Greg, sorry I was unclear as it say's Inherited users are not included in batch but I didn't realize that also covered inherited groups. 

Looking at your profile you sounds like the guy to ask, do you know if there is an API call that returns the original uploader/owner of a document in a team folder ?

Comment: No problem at all, the documentation could certainly be clearer. We'll make a note of that. As far as seeing the original creator of a file, I don't believe that's necessarily available via the API. (The endpoints addressed above are about sharing only, not the revisions/history of a file.) You can use [/2/files/list_revisions](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_revisions), but that may not always go back to the original version.

Comment: Thank you for your help Greg, I had also came to the conclusion that revision history might be the only way to go to get what I'm after. Cheers for the help ill mark this as solved now :)